# Change file last access time

Tags: powershell, batch-file, dos

I would like to change last access time on files by adding +20 years in future, in windows 2008 environment, I tried with by installing unix utility on my windows server and used `touch –a –t`  command it works but as I have every day new files In my path folder `z:\data\backup\*.bkf` so second time I’m not able to modify new files by skipping the old ones, which are already modified.

e.g. Command & output:

C:\unix\wbin>touch -a -t 120312002033 z:\data\backup*.bkf

Info: all files *.bkf in the path modified as follows:

created:    Today 9th December 2013
modify:     Today 9th December 2013
accessed:   Saturday 3rd December 2033

e.g. Imagine today I have 1000 files in  In my path folder `z:\data\backup\*.bkf` on which I already changed the last access time to +20 years and tomorrow I will have 1500 more files in the same folder with extension .bkf, so now I would like to change only those new files and take them to +20 years and keep on doing like this every day by skipping the already done files and touching only new ones, by running a batch.

Please Note: once I change the last access time and add +20 years, these files will be immediate locked in folder `z:\data\backup` for 20 years and cannot be deleted or modify but one can only read them, this is a
Retention lock feature of EMC Data Domain.

I`m not a cli or powershell expert.
I really appreciate your help and thanks a lot in advance for your time.

Best Regards,
Bobby.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well i give you something to work with:

```
get-childitem | select LastWriteTime
```

finally if you want to check each file for a specific date use:

```
get-childitem | foreach-object {
    if ($_.lastwritetime.year -eq 2013) {
        write-host $_.Name was created 2013
    } else {
        write-host $_ was not created 2013
    }
}
```

In Batch you would do it like this:

```
for /d %%f in (*) do @echo %%f is born on %%~tf
```

so you could in theory have something like:

```
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
for %%f in (*) do (
    set FILE_DATE="%%~tf"
    set FILE_YEAR=!FILE_DATE:~7,4!
    if !FILE_YEAR! == 2013 (
        echo %%f was born in 2013 
    ) else (
        echo %%f was not born in 2013
    )
)
```

But be carefull, first see what **%%~tf** will output on your machine, since the format of DateTime output often varies in different cultures. Essentially you have to work on the substring in !FILE_DATE!

**Final Edit:**

So this is as far as I go doing your job :)

```
new-variable now -value (date)
new-variable nact -value ((date).addyears(20))
get-childitem *.bkf | foreach-object {
    set-variable nact -value (($_.lastaccesstime).addyears(20))
    if ($_.lastaccesstime.year -le $now.year) {
        write-host [$now]: Updateing LastAccessTime of $_.name to $nact
        $_.lastaccesstime = ($nact)
    } else {
        write-host [$now]: Ignoring $_.name
    }
}
```

This will look at every ***.bkf** file in the current folder, and if it's last access time by year is lesser or equal to the current year, it will add 20 years to it's last access time. Every other file is left alone.

Comment: Hello i tried something like this seems not working but iam very close. thanks for your help

Comment: PS D:\> $files = Get-ChildItem "D:\folder1\*.bkp"; foreach( $f in $files) { $f.LastAccesstime = ($f.LastAccesstime).AddHours(23); }

Comment: PS D:\> $files = Get-ChildItem "D:\folder1\*.bkp"; foreach( $f in $files) { $f.LastAccesstime = ($f.LastAccesstime).Addyears(20); }

Comment: Well the issue with that, is that this will add 20 years to any file (even those, that already are at 2033)... you really should have an if block checking for the date before doing something

Comment: Yes, You are Right ! in fact i want to skip those files who are already at 2033 and should touch only the new ones which are at current date and add 20 years or a fixed date e.g. 12.12.2033. `m very close but not scripting in  right way and finishing with errors,  I really Appreciate your help as I desperately need  to find a solution, many thanks.

Comment: Have you looked at my post recently? In particular at the powershell foreach loop?

Comment: No, Actually I`m new here and really not familiar with batch files and scripting, you can say like I`m starting from really low level, but I will start reading you posts from now, may be it will help me as you are Senior.
Many thanks.

Comment: I was referring to the Answer we are commenting on right now. There is a foreach loop in powershell syntaxt (that i have tested), that does what you want to do. It distinguishes between files that have lastaccess in a specific year and those that are not.

Comment: Great Sir thank you, can i get the Exact what I`m looking for ? I mean in form of  lines already done so I will go ahead to run?

Comment: Ok use the last script i have appended to my post with the last edit (there is an explanation below, what it actually does...)

Comment: Thanks A lot Sir :) i will try this weekend. write you back

Comment: Sir, you sent me a piece of cake, it works exactly as I wanted, many thanks for your help with best regards.

Answer (score -1):

I personally would do this using C or something similar (not necessary but this is because I worked on something similar few days ago)

You could run over your files using opendir and readdir then stat or lstat all your files one by one you will then get a struct with a field st_atime you can compare it to time() because if st_atime is greater then the current timestamp then you are looking at a already modified one, if not, just update the st_atime.

Hope I was able to help you.